# When i click the button , It taking another function than the actual clicked function

Tags: javascript, html

when i click adult button , href  should take me to link-1 and when i click adult and children button it should take me to link-2 , but which ever button i click it taking me to link-1 only , as im new to development , im unable to figure this out , can any one help me with this please , below i have added my html and script both , one more doubt is , when i give script from app.js windows.open is not working , it working only when i give from same html file , may i know why ?

```
<div class=" my-3">
                <a target="_blank" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-h btn-block mx-2 btn-promo">
                  <button data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" class="link-text" onclick="adult()">
                    Adult
                  </button>
                </a>
                <a target="_blank" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-h btn-block mx-2 btn-promo">
                  <button data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" class="link-text" onclick="adultChild()">
                  Adult & Child
                  </button>
                </a>
              </div>
```

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Redirecting Alert</h5>
            <button type="button" onclick="reload()" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            Now you are redirecting to our partner site. <br><br>
            
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

```
<!-- Adult button Script -->
  <script>
    setTimeout (function adult() {
      var win = window.open();
      win.location = "www.link-1.com", "_blank";
      win.opener = null;
      win.blur();
      window.focus();
    },7000,false)
  </script>

  <!-- Adult&children button Script -->
  <script>
    setTimeout (function adultChild() {
      var win = window.open();
      win.location = "www.link-2.com", "_blank";
      win.opener = null;
      win.blur();
      window.focus();
    },7000)
  </script>
```

Comment: where are the `adult` and `adultChild` functions declared? the javascript you posted does NOT create functions that can be callled using `onclick=` so - you must have some other code somewhere

Comment: what your code actually does is call that those function after 7 seconds - no clicking required

Comment: what are changes should i do to work my condition, when i click adult i have modal saying your redirect to another site and after 7 sec with script im redirecting to that site , same for adult and children but diffrent link here @Bravo

Comment: the **code you've posted** will not do anything on a click - perhaps you should show the code that defines the (global) functions `adult` and `adultChild` that are called by clicking the buttons - so, clearly an important bit of code is missing from the question

Comment: `function adult() { do things here }` - clearly there's "other code" that deals with the `data-bs-*` attributes you have on the button, and clearly that's where the issue is - because **as written** clicking on those buttons will *do nothing* and show an error in the *developer* tools console - what errors can you see in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class=" my-3">
                <a target="_blank" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-h btn-block mx-2 btn-promo">
                  <button data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" class="link-text" onclick="adult()">
                    Adult
                  </button>
                </a>
                <a target="_blank" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-h btn-block mx-2 btn-promo">
                  <button data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" class="link-text" onclick="adultChild()">
                  Adult & Child
                  </button>
                </a>
              </div>

<script>
    function newadult(){
      var win = window.open();
      win.location = "www.link-1.com","_blank";
      win.opener = null;
      win.blur();
      window.focus();
    }


    function adult(){
      setTimeout(newadult,700)
    }


    function newadultChild(){
      var win = window.open();
      win.location = "www.link-2.com", "_blank";
      win.opener = null;
      win.blur();
      window.focus();
    }

    function adultChild(){
       setTimeout(newadultChild,700)
    }
      
  </script>
```

Comment: no its still gng to the same link-1 @Preetham

Comment: check now i changed the code for it is working...

Comment: yes its working Thankyou @Preetham Koushik